# How do I call fork() directly, bypassing libc?

Tags: linux, posix, fork

I installed a SIGSEV and SIGABRT signal handler which forks a child process that:
1. stops its parent process with SIGSTOP.
2. invokes gdb on the parent process to gather crash diagnostics.

Problem is, [fork is not async signal safe on glibc](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=4737) thanks to ptmalloc installing pthread_atfork handlers. Now my signal handler has the potential to freeze because fork() tries to allocate memory, which in turn may grab a mutex that's already locked.

I want to work around this problem by calling the fork system call directly, bypassing any libc wrappers and therefore bypassing any atfork handlers. How do I do that? The following code works on Linux, but doesn't seem to work on OS X. It always returns the child PID, never 0, or is it supposed to do that? I'm also not sure whether I'm capturing the return value correctly because the definition is `int syscall(...)` but fork returns an integer of type `pid_t`.

```
pid = syscall(SYS_fork);
```

My app runs on many platforms, including Linux and OS X.

EDIT: fix typo: s/thread safe/async signal safe/.

Comment: Sorry, but if your app is supposed to run on many platforms, I cannot see how invoking the platform-dependent `syscall()` would help you in the slightest...

Comment: Why don't you write a wrapper for `fork()` that locks/unlocks a mutex around the call, so it becomes thread-safe?

Comment: As I understand the bug you link, that is relevant if you call `fork` from a signal handler, not from different threads. That is, `fork()` is not async-signal safe. There is no mention about it not being thread safe. Did you suffer this bug? Or are you just being extra careful?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: I can just use #ifdefs.

Comment: @Shahbaz: I can't, I don't have access to ptmalloc's mutexes. And there was a typo: I meant async signal safe, not thread safe.

Comment: @rodrigo: Yes I meant async signal safe; it was a typo. I am being extra careful in my signal handler, I've even written my own strlen() and I use an alternative stack just to be safe.

Comment: You could try with `posix_spawn()`... it looks like an async-signal safe replacement for `fork()`.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, if you just want to automatically fire a debugger on software core dumping signals, you could make your core dump piping into some script, according to [core(5)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/core.5.html) you just need to start your `coredump_filter`  with a `|`  (pipe character followed by command).

This trick avoids any extra programming (except for the script you make for that)